# JSON.parse() fails when a string contains the "null" substring... for example with italian words like "annullo" or "annullare"

Tags: javascript, json, null, substring, escaping

Good morning everyone and thank you in advance for any suggestions. I have written a small web application to perform simple searches in a stamps database using php and javascript.

The server sends to the browser the whole database as a JSON and the queries are done client-side with a javascript code.
The JSON has this structure:
`{"ck":0,"db":[["string11","string12","string13"],["string21","string22","string23"], etc... } .`

Until now the system has worked perfectly and over 1500 stamps could be shown.
Suddenly it stopped working and, in the browser's Javascript console, this error message appeared:
`VM672:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Expected ',' or ']' after array element in JSON at position 97506 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) ...etc...`

After a series of tests, by exclusion I came to discover that it was the word "annullo" in the last added record to generate the error.

I guess it could be the substring "null" to give problems, but I have no idea how to escape it.
A really strange thing is that, whilst failing with the `JSON.parse()` function, browser's javascript console, as well as other json validation tools, recognise the server's response as a valid JSON.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: A string like `"anullo"` would be valid JSON. And it should never be mistaken for `null` otherwise the whole concept of JSON encoding fails. https://jsbin.com/govuroh/edit?js,console

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: 2023-02-01:
Actually, I found the problem: client side I had this command a few lines before parsing: `data = data.replaceAll("null","\"\"");` , where data is the json as a string, as received from server.
I'll do some changes to make this replacement no more necessary...

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

As @Andrea Soffiantini pointed in a comment, this was the actual problem:

> Client side I had this command a few lines before parsing: `data = data.replaceAll("null","\"\"");` , where data is the json as a string, as received from server.

This replaces the string `"anullo"` with `"a""o"`, which is invalid in JSON syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the problem. All strings are enclosed in quotes.

```
{example: "example"}
```

In the development of this case they must have put "annullo" but they forgot to insert the quotes. If it was null, **not a string**, it could look like this, without quotes.

json = {example: null}

However, as annullo is an invalid word in javascript and is not as a string, it gives an error.

The correct thing to do is to correct the error in the source, transforming it to null, however, I believe that you can also use this regular expression. But do tests to ensure that there is no undue substitution elsewhere.

```
json.replace(/.+["']: ?annull(o|are)[\n,}]$/g, matched => {
    return matched.replace(/annull(o|are)/, 'null')
})
```